# Trigger keyboard event with greasemonkey or tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I created an user script for periodically deleting history from Google Chrome. The easiest way I could think of was to install `Clear Cache` https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=en, which lets you configure a keyboard shortcut for deleting history. The shortcut I set was `alt+9`

This is the code I use to trigger `alt+9` event when I open a desired webpage.

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event'); 
event.initEvent('keydown', true, true); 
event.keyCode = 18&&57;
document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The history doesn't get cleared when I visit target website and I am not sure why. Is the event I dispatched not the same as pressing `alt+9`? Upon manually pressing `alt+9`, the shortcut does indeed work.

Edit: Also tried

```
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant        GM_info

    var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.altKey = true;
press.which = 57;
$("whatever").trigger(press);

function GM_main ($) {
    //alert ('jQuery is installed with no conflicts! The version is: ' + $.fn.jquery);
}

if (typeof jQuery === "function") {
    console.log ("Running with local copy of jQuery!");
    GM_main (jQuery);  
}
else {
    console.log ("fetching jQuery from some 3rd-party server.");
    add_jQuery (GM_main, "2.2.2");
}

function add_jQuery (callbackFn, jqVersion) {
    var jqVersion   = jqVersion || "2.2.2";
    var D           = document;
    var targ        = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    var scriptNode  = D.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.src  = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/'
                    + jqVersion
                    + '/jquery.min.js'
                    ;
    scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", function () {
        var scriptNode          = D.createElement ("script");
        scriptNode.textContent  =
            'var gm_jQuery  = jQuery.noConflict (true);\n'
            + '(' + callbackFn.toString () + ')(gm_jQuery);'
        ;
        targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
    }, false);
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.keyCode = 18&&57;` does **not** work. This is a logical/boolean operation and results actually in 57 because 18 evaluates to true, so the second operand is assigned.

Also a binary operation `18&57` would not represent `alt+9`. To simulate a `keydown 9` while alt-key is held down you have to give a `keycode` of 57 and set the alt-indicator to true.

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent();
event.keyCode = 57;
event.which   = 57;
event.altKey  = true;
event.ctrlKey = false;
event.shiftKey= false;
event.target  = window;
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Doing so you can manipulate webapplication, however, you can **not** access browser features, since this could be done by any website, which would mean a high security risk.

Userscripts are not much more privileged than websites. You could develop an addon to have comprehensive access to the browser gui. There are templates/boilerplates for developing addons. It's just JavaScript zipped to an .xpi-file.

Answer (score 0):

This code I added to a script of mine for Greasemonkey

```
function End(){ var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'End', code: 'End', which: 35, keyCode: 35, });
window.dispatchEvent(event); }
```

When calling `End();` in any place in the script , it will simulate pressing END key